# Creating a CSV file from Python Script

Tags: python

I am learning data mining from a book and I am trying to write my first script to gather info from Youtube's API and feed it into a new .csv file. For some reason, it isn't working. I tried inputting the script line by line in a CLI and the script will eventually create an empty .csv file, but the information is never fed in. Here is my code, it's basically copied line by line from the book:

```
import csv
import json
import requests

api_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCJFp8uSYCjXOMnkUyb3CQ3Q&key=AIzaSyDaMzUYRFzDfjMq-bTm38Y_1swWDMfg03E"
api_response = requests.get(api_url)
videos = json.loads(api_response.text)

with open("C:\Users\jacks\Documents\PythonScripts\youtube_videos.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(["publishedAt",
                 "title",
                 "description",
                 "thumbnailurl"])
    if videos.get("items") is not None:
        for video in videos.get("items"):
            videos_data_row = [
                video["snippet"]["publishedAt"],
                video["snippet"]["title"],
                video["snippet"]["description"],
                video["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["default"]["url"]
                ]
            csv_writer.writerow(video_data_row)
```

Comment: Theres a typo in `csv_writer.writerow(video_data_row)`

Comment: Also, for future reference please check [ask]. _For some reason, it isn't working._ - you get specific error that says what and where the problem is. So, it is clear what the problem is. Always post the full traceback you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code & the only problem I found was in `csv_writer.writerow(video_data_row)`

You're missing an `s`

Replace with:

```
csv_writer.writerow(videos_data_row)
```